# OkHttp3 Multiple request tag

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am assigning the tag to OkHttp Request like,

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .tag(requestTag)
    .build();
```

and I can cancel that particular request by that using

```
public static void cancel(Object tag) {
    for (Call call : getClient().dispatcher().queuedCalls()) {
        if (tag.equals(call.request().tag())) call.cancel();
    }
    for (Call call : getClient().dispatcher().runningCalls()) {
        if (tag.equals(call.request().tag())) call.cancel();
    }
}
```

But how to assign multiple tag to request because I have to track the request and if any request has timeout then I have to cancel the related tag request

Any idea?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Change your application to always use a `Set` for its tags. In your canceling code you’ll need to downcast.

Comment: I had a similar question as the OP. Can you please explain your answer in more detail?